# Where to save a reusable static jar to be used from an Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, jar, pipeline

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline
The pipeline has a "command line" task that runs a java command on a jar file
The jar file is a static one that represents a tool to be used in the build process.
The jar file is not created as part of the build pipeline. It's just a jar with one version and it doesn't change with each build

Where is the best place to save this jar file and how to download it to the agent during the build pipeline execution ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the jar file is static one and not created as part of the build pipeline, you can save the jar file to **Azure Artifacts Feed -> Universal Package**.

To upload the jar file to Azure Artifacts Universal Package, you can use [Universal Packages Task - Publish command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/universal-packages?view=azure-devops) in Pipeline or Azure CLI command: [az artifacts universal publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops#publish-universal-packages) (work in pipeline or local machine).

Then you can use the task: [Universal Packages Task - Download command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/universal-packages?view=azure-devops) to download the Universal Package during the build pipeline execution.